# ArcGIS 10.1 crashes when a button in an addin invokes GDAL DLL through SWIG CSharp wrapper

Tags: arcgis-10.1, gdal, c#, add-in

I am developing an addin with a button that tries to do coordinate transformation using GDAL OSR. When I create a new CoordinateTransformation object ArcMap crashes and close. If a debug against a debug osr_csharp.dll I can see that CoordinateTransformation object is throwing an exception with this message: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (proj.dll), creation of\nOGRCoordinateTransformation failed. I have checked the addin file unziping it and I can see it contains the proj.dll and all the dependencies that osr_csharp.dll should have.

The rare thing is that the same code executed inside an EXE project works without problem. Where is ArcGIS deploying addins? I cannot see the folder where ArcGIS is supposed to be uncompressing the addin file?

Any ideas on this type of fail?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Don't cross the streams..."

Comment: I don't have my ArcMap machine right now but I think debugged add-ins might be extracted to C:\Users\<name>\Local Settings\ESRI\DesktopX.X\AssemblyCache. Also, count your blessings - my ArcMap 10.1 crashes before it even loads :(

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The path is like that more or less. I have found it in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.1.

Comment: A colleague has found for me that the AssemblyCache is hidden because it is marked as system file, so it is needed to uncheck the option to hide system files in folder tools. Now I can see the content of may addin as it is unzipped. And I can ensure that all dependencies in my addin are added. So still my problem persists...